# SQL y Java: La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados. en tabla temporal

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, requiero ejecutar la siguiente instruccion SQL desde Java, crear un tabla temporal para después hacer un SELECT y poder obtener los datos para desplegarlos, en SQL funciona muy bien,  sin embargo desde Java me manda el error:"La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados." ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? la instruccion de aquí abajo es tal cual la pongo en Java, así es como me la imprime en consola

```
DECLARE @VariableTabla TABLE (cort_efe DECIMAL, cort_vunicheck DECIMAL, cort_ovales DECIMAL, 
rec_efe DECIMAL, rec_cert DECIMAL, rec_val_cred DECIMAL, rec_dolares DECIMAL)
INSERT INTO @VariableTabla VALUES 
((SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS cort_efe FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=1 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=2),
(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS cort_vunicheck FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=8 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=2),
(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS cort_ovales FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=12 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=2),
(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_efe FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=1 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=1),
(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_cert FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=10 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=1),
(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_val_cred FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=9 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=1),
(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_dolares FROM co_transacciones
WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=6 AND id_compania=1 AND co_tr_tienda=1 AND co_tr_tip_mov=1));
SELECT * FROM @VariableTabla
```

```java
String SQL = "begin try drop table #tmpINGRESOS end try\r\n" + 
                    "begin catch end catch "+
                     "CREATE TABLE #tmpINGRESOS (cort_efe DECIMAL, cort_vunicheck DECIMAL, cort_ovales DECIMAL, "+
                     "rec_efe DECIMAL, rec_cert DECIMAL, rec_val_cred DECIMAL, rec_dolares DECIMAL)\r\n" + 
                    "INSERT INTO #tmpINGRESOS VALUES \r\n" + 
                    "((SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS cort_efe FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=1 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=2),\r\n" + 
                    "(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS cort_vunicheck FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=8 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=2),\r\n" + 
                    "(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS cort_ovales FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=12 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=2),\r\n" + 
                    "(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_efe FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=1 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=1),\r\n" + 
                    "(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_cert FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=10 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=1),\r\n" + 
                    "(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_val_cred FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                    "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=9 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=1),\r\n" +
                    "(SELECT SUM(co_tr_impo) AS rec_dolares FROM co_transacciones\r\n" + 
                            "WHERE co_tr_tip_fp=6 AND id_compania="+ id_compañia+" AND co_tr_tienda="+tienda+" AND co_tr_tip_mov=1));";
                    
            System.out.println(SQL);
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            stmt.executeUpdate();           
            SQL="SELECT * FROM #tmpINGRESOS";
            con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            System.out.println(SQL);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Subi el código con la modificacion que hice, sin embargo me arroja el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar explicitamente la creación de tabla (`CREATE TABLE`) y el nombre de la tabla debe tener `#` por ejemplo debe ser `#MiTablaTemporal`; entonces realizas los `INSERT`s y todas las operaciones que requieras, y finalmente tu `SELECT` para devolver tus datos.

Te sugiero luego del `SELECT` como ultima instrucción incluir el `DROP TABLE` para liberar explícitamente lo usado por la tabla temporal.